# how to take the database out of recovery mode?

Tags: postgresql

I need to take my PostgreSQL database out of recovery mode.

I have had to reinstall PostgreSQL using homebrew.

When I look to start the database using `brew services start postgresql` and then type `psql postgres` I receive the following error:

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode

I receive the following error in the log:

> Could not find relation mapping for relation "pg_database", OID 1262

How can I sort this out?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: "I have had to reinstall PostgreSQL using homebrew."  Why? It seems like the answer to your question lies in this untold tale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to *promote* the instance as operating system user `postgres`:

```bash
/path/to/postgres/bin/pg_ctl promote -D /path/to/data/direcory
```